# Retrieving all the date and names from each text cell in a column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column named descript which stores all the notes for each work order. I want to retrieve all the dates and names from each cell. Since one work order can have multiple notes, I want to find a way to find all the dates and names from each cell. 
1. Each cell is a text field. All the data for each cell from Descript column is in this manner

```
09/30/2015 3:56PM Eastern Standard Time - Name  rest of the note...... 09/30/2015 1:15pm Eastern Standard Time - Name rest of the other note.
```

I am new to SQL Server so, I am having a hard time getting all the names and times so far, I have being using Charindex and Substring to get the first two names, but it is not easy and getting way too complicated.

```
SUBSTRING(descript,0,10) as Date,
SUBSTRING(descript, CHARINDEX('-', descript, 1)+1,charindex(' ',substring(descript,CHARINDEX('-', descript, 1)+2,datalength(descript)))) as Name.
```

This is what I have been using to get the first date and name. I am using name format to retrieve the rest, but I am doing it manually.

I want to find a way to loop through and find all the dates and names from each cell and output it

sample data

```
 CREATE TABLE Table_Tasks(
WO_NUM              INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
,Opendate            DATE  NOT NULL
 ,ClosedDate          DATE  NOT NULL
,Note                TEXT  NULL


 );
    INSERT INTO Table_Tasks(WO_NUM,Opendate,ClosedDate,Note) VALUES 
   (1,'5/30/2017',' 6/5/2017','05/30/2017 12:25am Eastern Standard Time - Mjames 
   reported changes in the pages 05/30/2017 10:35AM Rachael agreed to work on 
   the report and report to James 05/30/2017 10:00 AM James reports errors in 
   page.',NULL);

  INSERT INTO Table_Tasks(WO_NUM,Opendate,ClosedDate,Note) VALUES 
  (2,'6/1/2017','6/1/2017','06/1/2017 3:20PM Eastern Standard Time -  
  Rsubramaniam reported phone is not functional 06/1/2017 4:00PM Service took 
  the phone and replaced it with new one');
```

OUTPUT

```
#WO_NUM     Date    Name           Date     Name       Date      Name #
1        5/30/2017  Mjames        5/30/2017 Jrachael   5/30/2017 Mjames
2        6/1/2017   Rsubramaniam  6/1/2017  Rtavern
```

Comment: If you got the chance, change the data design. Have one column for the date and one for the text of the note. And one note corresponds to one row.

Comment: I would love that, but I have to work with this format right now. This is why its not easy for me

Comment: Do u always have same format text in cells ?

Comment: yes the format is the same. A new note always starts with 09/30/2015 3:56PM Eastern Standard Time - Name and extra space then the date and time starts

Comment: date and time each time that was just the example

Comment: You mean each text column has 2 datetime values ?

Comment: each cell in descript column can have multiple date and names.

Comment: Do u mind pasting one sample note (row value) completely in your question designer please

Comment: In order to help we need some details. See [this article](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some great ideas on what you should post.

Comment: I will edit the post and add a sample data and output required. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First loop in answer should be adjusted to match your data structures. In #tmp2 table id, data and name from first table will be saved.

```
create table #tmp1
(
    Id int not null identity(1,1),  
    descript nvarchar(256)
)   

insert into #tmp1 (descript)
values ('09/30/2015 3:56PM Eastern Standard Time - Name1  rest of the note...... 09/30/2018 1:15pm Eastern Standard Time - Name2 rest of the other note. 09/30/2008 1:15pm Eastern Standard Time - NameXXX rest of the other note.'),
    ('09/30/2017 3:56PM Eastern Standard Time - Name3  rest of the note...... 09/30/2018 1:15pm Eastern Standard Time - Name4 rest of the other note.')

create table #tmp2
(
    id int,
    [date] nvarchar(256),
    name nvarchar(256)
)   

declare @Id int
declare @count int

declare @name nvarchar(256)
declare @date nvarchar(256)
declare @desc nvarchar(256)

declare @dateposition int
declare @nameposition int
declare @nameend int

select @count = MAX(id) from #tmp1
set @id = 1;
while (@id <= @count)
begin

select @desc = descript from #tmp1 where Id = @Id

    while (patindex('%[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%',@desc) > 0)
    begin
        set @dateposition = patindex('%[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9]%',@desc)
        set @date = SUBSTRING(@desc,@dateposition,10)

        set @nameposition = CHARINDEX('-', @desc)+2
        set @nameend = CHARINDEX(' ', @desc, @nameposition)+1
        set @name = SUBSTRING(@desc,@nameposition,@nameend-@nameposition)

        insert into #tmp2 
        values (@Id, @date, @name)

        set @desc = SUBSTRING(@desc,@nameend,1024)  
    end

set @id = @id + 1;

end

select * from #tmp2
```

Result:

```
id  date    name
1   09/30/2015  Name1 
1   09/30/2018  Name2 
1   09/30/2008  NameXXX 
2   09/30/2017  Name3 
2   09/30/2018  Name4
```

Comment: would it be possible to output all the date and name in single row. For example,       all the id  = 1 date , name would display in separate column instead of rows

Comment: If you know maximum number of possible columns then you can create #tmp2 with columns like date1, name1, date2, name2 etc and in second while loop insert into proper columns using dynamic sql and some counter variable. I don't have now access to Sql Server to show example.

Comment: i dont know how many columns i might need. I understand thank you